# auto generated robots.txt problem

Tags: wp-admin, seo, robots.txt, privacy

I have a site visibility in privacy settings set to allow search engines to see my site but for some reason when i go to the auto generated robots.txt file it shows

User-agent: *
Disallow:

switching site visibility merely adds/removes a trailing slash ie "Disallow: /"

i have 2 related plugins "all in one seo tools" and "google xml sitemaps" but i disabled both of these to no avail

any ideas anyone .... i know how to override this with a manual sitemap but i'm trying to find out whether this is WordPress intended behavior and if so why

Comment: I think I found the answer to this. Apparently Disallow: with no trailing slash is the same as Allow All .... however google doesn't fully comply with this. There is a very good discussion here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/robotstxt-set-to-disallow-cant-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disallow with no trailing slash is the same as "allow all" - [see here](http://www.webconfs.com/what-is-robots-txt-article-12.php) -  nice find!